# Set UILabel character limit?

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

I have a UILabel that shows the outside temperature, the problem is, sometimes it shows it as a XX.XXº format instead of the normal XXº or XXXº format used to show temperature, is there anyway to force the label to only show the temperature without the decimals or at least force it to only be able to use 2 characters?

Comment: Use a NSNumberFormatter to format the string before displaying it. This way you'll be able to decide how many decimals (if any) you want to show.

Comment: Show your code for converting your number to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to eliminate the decimals:

```
NSString* numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", d]; // 0 means no decimals
```

Otherwise I believe this will work to limit the number of chars to 2:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.usesSignificantDigits = YES;
formatter.maximumSignificantDigits = 2;
```

I have not really used NSNumberFormatter very much though.

Comment: NSString *numberString =[NSStringstringWithFormat:@".0",tmpstring]; Crashes.. :/

Comment: make sure it is **@"%.0f"** NOT @".0" also d is a double or float, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *temp = [galleryEntryTree objectForKey:@"description"];
if ([temp length] > 500) {
    NSRange range = [temp rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:(NSRange){0, 500}];
    temp = [temp substringWithRange:range];
    temp = [temp stringByAppendingString:@" …"];
}
coverView.label2.text = temp;
```

Answer (score -1):

You may also use substring method

```
 NSString *newformat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[temperature substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,2)]];
```

In this case temperature is a string that you set for your label and you are only retrieving the 1st 2 digits only

Comment: What happens with a value of 5 or 100?

Comment: You can use a number formatter and then
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];

Comment: I was pointing out that your answer will fail if `temperature` is not 2 characters.

Comment: im just stating that as an example you can always check how many digits are there before applying the substring method